# Show Post Content with AJAX

Tags: ajax, javascript

I want to do a very basic AJAX call where, on click of a list item, a container div fills with associated content pulled from a Wordpress page. I'm a newb with AJAX; I've tried a few different routes today but to no avail. I got the page to load in the container but I want only the post content (as if I called the_content() in the div but doing it AJAX style). I only have three pages I would like to pull from.

Does anyone know of a simple way to accomplish this? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create the [JSON endpoint](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/) that accepts a [`WP_Post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) ID.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'api/v2', '/post/(?<id>\d+)', array (
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_post_content',
    ) );
} );
```

Handle the endpoint to return a post's content based on the ID passed.

```
function get_post_content( WP_REST_Request $request ) {

    $post = get_post( absint( $request->get_param( 'id' ) ) );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        return 'Invalid ID';
    }

    return apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
}
```

Get the data with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
<script>
jQuery.get( "/wp-json/api/v2/post/504", function( data ) {

    jQuery( ".result" ).html( data );

});
</script>
```

---

(Optional) - [Localize](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/authentication/#cookie-authentication) the [REST URL](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_rest_url/) .

```
wp_localize_script( 'wp-api', 'wpApiSettings', array( 'root' => esc_url_raw( rest_url() ) ) );

<script>
jQuery.get( wpApiSettings.root + "api/v2/post/504", function( data ) {
    jQuery( ".result" ).html( data );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna need a PHP code like this, you can add it to the functions.php, or I would recommend creating a plugin.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_action_name', 'ajax_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_action_name', 'ajax_function');


function ajax_function(){

$post = get_post($_POST['post_id']);

$response = array("content"=> apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content));
$response = json_encode($response);
echo $response;
die();

}
```

You also need Javascript to make the call:

```
var data = {
        'action': 'action_name'
        'post_id' : id //you can get it with jQuery

    };
jQuery.post(AJAX_URL , data, function(response) {


 //do what you need with the response

}
```

The AJAX_URL is located in domain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, you can generate it with `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`

You can read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). Remember to include jQuery, the recommended way to do it is using wp_enqueue_script, [more here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript).

This code wasn't tested, so expect some syntactic errors, at least.